# Jboss only works on localhost:8080 ,but doesnt reply when called by ip

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, java-server

I installed JBoss 5.0.1
and ran it , but when i called it from the same computer on localhost:8080 it works
but when i call it from other computer it doesnt work at all using the computer IP ... when i had tomcat it used to work on both.so Does anybody know the problem?

Comment: What options are you using on startup?  What is the value of the -b parameter in the run script?

Answer (score 18):

If you want JBoss to communicate on all IP addresses that are on the machine, then you can start it with the -b option passing 0.0.0.0 as the ip address, e.g.

```
-b 0.0.0.0
```

Probably better is binding to the specific IP address that you want to.  You can do this  again by using the -b option, but passing the IP address you want to bind to or the DNS name you want to bind to, e.g.

```
-b 192.168.0.1
```

or
    -b *jbosshostname*

You can put the -b option in the run.bat file so it is used automatically if you are running JBoss as a service - assuming Windows.  If you are not using Windows, you can place this option in the run.sh file.

If you do not wish to put the -b option in the run.sh/bat file, you can enter it at the command line:

```
run.bat -b 192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 10):

Solution to jboss 7 is the same, but with the addition of `-bmanagement` for the management interface

```
-b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 127.0.0.1
```

If you prefer do set this permanently in config file you may edit file `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` from :

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

to:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Comment: worth to mention, touching `standalone.xml` for a jboss started within eclipse, doesn't seem to work. You need to add `-b 0.0.0.0` to program arguments (in launch configuration)

Comment: Also, uncheck `Always update arguments related to the runtime`.

Answer (score 1):

Run JBoss with `-b` option:

```
$ ./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```

(on Windows):

```
> run.bat -b 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the run.bat or run.sh  accordingly  including binding  -b 0.0.0.0 .

or you can run the jboss by command line by following command.

run -b 0.0.0.0